# Make colorbox show vertically centered characters when using \strut

Tags: fontspec, colorbox

- The context
- The problem
- The question

## The context

I know that it is possible to show text in colored boxes by using `\colorbox`. Because the characters have different sizes, the height of the boxes is different.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{color}
\pagecolor{blue}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{red}{This}\colorbox{green}{is}\colorbox{red}{a}\colorbox{green}{sentence}\colorbox{red}{.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also know that it is possible to make all boxes to have equal height by using `\strut`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{red}{\strut This}\colorbox{green}{\strut is}\colorbox{red}{\strut a}\colorbox{green}{\strut sentence}\colorbox{red}{\strut .}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've now installed a monospaced font for Chinese characters. If I use `\colorbox`, all characters are shown in the vertical center of their corresponding colored boxes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{color}
\pagecolor{blue}

\begin{document}
\fontspec[Path = \string~/.fonts/]{NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular}
\colorbox{red}{你}\colorbox{green}{好}\colorbox{red}{国}\colorbox{green}{工}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## The problem

I want all boxes to have equal height. Therefore, I use `\strut`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\fontspec[Path = \string~/.fonts/]{NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular}
\colorbox{red}{\strut 你}\colorbox{green}{\strut 好}\colorbox{red}{\strut 国}\colorbox{green}{\strut 工}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is that now, all characters are not shown in the vertical center of the corresponding colored boxes. The following two screenshots are the measurements obtained through Inkscape of the last two characters. In the first screenshot, the spacing between the character and the top border is **1.21mm**, while the spacing between the character and the bottom border is **2.04mm**. In the second screenshot, the spacing between the character and the top border is **1.45mm** and the bottom border is **2.31mm**.

[image]

[image]

## The question

Given a sentence containing Chinese characters which are colored by using `\colorbox`, how to make all colored boxes have the same height and make the characters be vertically aligned in the corresponding colored boxes.

Comment: just remove the strut. it is needed for Latin as p and y have descenders and A is taller than o but Chinese characters are same height and have no descender

Comment: You can use a zero-width rule instead of the strut to have complete control over the height and depth of the box (`\rule[-3pt]{0pt}{8pt}` or something like that).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

A colorbox always uses equal space (`\fboxsep`) on all four sides.

1. Latin characters have different height and depth
2. a strut adds invisible content taller and deeper than all latin characters so all boxes are forced equal
3. It is easier to see if you use a strut that is not 0pt wide, so you can see it
4. If you just want larger spacing, you do not need a strut for Chinese, just increase `\fboxsep`
5. If you want to keep the horizontal space but increase vertical use a (visible) strut more suited to Chinese, with 5pt higher than the character and 5pt depth
6. and the same with an invisible strut

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand\xstrut{\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{2pt}{\baselineskip}}

\newcommand\xcstrut{\sbox0{你}\rule[-5pt]{2pt}{\dimexpr\ht0+10pt}}
\newcommand\cstrut{\sbox0{你}\rule[-5pt]{0pt}{\dimexpr\ht0+10pt}}


\begin{document}

1

\colorbox{red}{A}\colorbox{green}{x}\colorbox{red}{y}


{\fontspec{NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular}
\colorbox{red}{你}\colorbox{green}{好}\colorbox{red}{国}\colorbox{green}{工}}


2

\colorbox{red}{\strut A}\colorbox{green}{\strut x}\colorbox{red}{\strut y}


{\fontspec{NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular}
\colorbox{red}{\strut 你}\colorbox{green}{\strut 好}\colorbox{red}{\strut 国}\colorbox{green}{\strut 工}}

3

\colorbox{red}{\xstrut A}\colorbox{green}{\xstrut x}\colorbox{red}{\xstrut y}

{\fontspec{NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular}
\colorbox{red}{\xstrut 你}\colorbox{green}{\xstrut 好}\colorbox{red}{\xstrut 国}\colorbox{green}{\xstrut 工}}

{

4
\setlength\fboxsep{5pt}

\colorbox{red}{\strut A}\colorbox{green}{\strut x}\colorbox{red}{\strut y}


{\fontspec{NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular}
\colorbox{red}{你}\colorbox{green}{好}\colorbox{red}{国}\colorbox{green}{工}}
}


{
5

\colorbox{red}{\xstrut A}\colorbox{green}{\xstrut x}\colorbox{red}{\xstrut y}

{\fontspec{NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular}
\colorbox{red}{\xcstrut 你}\colorbox{green}{\xcstrut 好}\colorbox{red}{\xcstrut 国}\colorbox{green}{\xcstrut 工}}
}

{
6

\colorbox{red}{\strut A}\colorbox{green}{\strut x}\colorbox{red}{\strut y}

{\fontspec{NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular}
\colorbox{red}{\cstrut 你}\colorbox{green}{\cstrut 好}\colorbox{red}{\cstrut 国}\colorbox{green}{\cstrut 工}}
}
\end{document}
```

---

You have similar issues in Latin scripts if using all capitals. As shown above, the strut works best for `x`; it is a compromise for `A` and `y`. So if writing all caps where there are no descenders apart from Q in most fonts, it often looks best to use a modified strut that has more height and smaller depth as for Chinese.

In 1. and 4. above where no strut is used for Chinese, I would have expected all the boxes to have same height but apparently not and `工` is smaller. So for this font 4. (just using fboxsep) doesn't really work and you'll want 6. (you could increase `\fboxsep` as well of course)

Answer (score 2):

The characters don't have the same height and depth.

I suggest to use one as a specimen, having the largest height and depth.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newfontface{\zhtt}{NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular.otf}

\NewDocumentCommand{\zhttbox}{mm}{% #1 = color, #2 = character
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
  \colorbox{#1}{\zhtt\vphantom{你}\smash{#2}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\zhttbox{red!70}{你}\zhttbox{green!70}{好}\zhttbox{red!70}{国}\zhttbox{green!70}{工}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The boxes don't really align in the picture, due to artifacts in color rendering. Here's the image if I use `gray!60` for all of them:

[image]

Also adding the baseline

[image]